# MUI: The Menu component doesn't accept a Fragment as a child. Consider providing an array instead

Tags: material-ui

I have used `MUI` `Menu` with some `MenuItem`. But I keep getting the error : `MUI: The Menu component doesn't accept a Fragment as a child. Consider providing an array instead.` . Can anyone explain the error in simple text please? I have seen many similar explanations online but none of them seem clear to me. I have seen the very first [Q&A](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/16181), but doesn't explain much to me. I have taken this simple example from MUI's webpage. But I still getting the error. How to solve it in similar context?

I do not have any array to work with. Each of my `MenuItem` will be custom made.

```
  const DataMenu = ({ anchor, onClick, onClose }: Props) => (
  <Menu
    id="data-menu"
    anchorEl={anchor}
    open={Boolean(anchor)}
    onClose={onClose}
  >
    <MenuItem onClick={onClick}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <Db1 />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <Typography>Data 1</Typography>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={onClose}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <Db2 />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <Typography>Data 2</Typography>
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
);

export default DataMenu;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that source code explain better - https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Menu/Menu.js#L134

There is a check *isFragment(child)*. It means if one of your child is wrapped in Fragment, then you will see the error.

But your code looks valid.

That code snippet is **NOT** ok and throw the error:

```
 <Menu>
    <>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
    </>
 </Menu>
```

That code snippet is OK:

```
 <Menu>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
 </Menu>
```

Comment: I understand it better now. But strange that I get this error still. Have to dig down in other places I presume.

Comment: @PineCone may you share the code somehow, I will try to help then.

Comment: I would have if I knew where is it coming from :). If I can't dig down, I will ping you.

Comment: for me it seemed that putting a div/Box instead of an empty fragment, <>, did the trick

Comment: I think even if you wrap it in `div` you're still screwing up the selectedItem logic.